# Sending emails using multiple attachments using powershell script

Tags: powershell

I have the following variable stored

```
PS C:>$PathArray
jagbir.singh1990@gmail.com
mr.singh@gmail.com

PS C:>$PathArray2
805775-1.zip
805775-2.zip

$Arrayresult = for ( $i = 0; $i -lt $max; $i++)
  {
      Write-Verbose "$($PathArray[$i]),$($PathArray2[$i])"
      [PSCustomObject]@{
          PathArray = $PathArray
          PathArray2 = $PathArray2
   
      }

PS C:>$Arrayresult

PathArray                                            PathArray2                                       
---------                                            ----------                                       
{jagbir.singh1990@gmail.com, mr.singh@gmail.com...}  {805775-1.zip, 805775-2.zip...}
{jagbir.singh1990@gmail.com, mr.singh@gmail.com...}  {805775-1.zip, 805775-2.zip...}
```

I want to send email1 with body text containing zip file1 name and email2 with body text containing zip file2 name

Ex:
From : jagbir.singh1990@gmail.com

Body : 805775-1.zip file transfer successful.

**No Attachments required**

code:

```
foreach($X in $Arrayresult){
    Send-MailMessage -From $X.Patharray -To 'jagbir.singh1990@gmail.com' -Subject 'File Transfer completed successfully' -body 'File $X.PathArray2 transfer success'  -smtpServer 'smtp.gmail.com' -Port 465
}
Write-Host "Email sent.."
```

How can I seperate each email for each zip file
email1 --> file1
email2 --> file2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would want to keep the email addresses and filenames in separate arrays and then combine them in an array of PSObjects for this.

Anyway, the first mistake is that you did not specify a value for variable `$max`, which should be the count for the smallest of the two arrays (I'm using more descriptive variable names for these arrays):

```
$max = [math]::Min($email.Count, $files.Count)
```

The second one is that you are adding the complete arrays in the properties of each PSCustomObject you create instead of one element of the input arrays.

Finally, I would suggest using a simpler loop (not creating a new PSObject array), use [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) for the parameters of `Send-MailMessage` and add some error checking while sending:

Something like:

```
# array of email addresses to send TO
$email = 'jagbir.singh1990@gmail.com', 'mr.singh@gmail.com'
# array of filenames to use in the mail body
$files = '805775-1.zip', '805775-2.zip'

# determine the max number of iterations
$max = [math]::Min($email.Count, $files.Count)

# set up a hashtable for splatting the parameters to the Send-MailMessage cmdlet
$mailParams = @{
    From = 'me@gmail.com'
    Subject = 'File Transfer completed successfully' 
    SmtpServer = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    Port = 465
    # other parameters go here
}

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $max; $i++) {
    # inside the loop we add/update the parameters 'To' and 'Body'
    $mailParams['To'] = $email[$i]
    $mailParams['Body'] = "File $($files[$i]) transfer success" 

    try {
        Send-MailMessage @mailParams -ErrorAction Stop
        Write-Host "Email sent.."
    }
    catch {
        Write-Error "Email NOT sent.`r`n$($_.Exception.Message)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Theo, Thanks for your reply with code. This code works with multiple files and sends multiple email, However for a single file, it throws error ```The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address.+ CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException``` Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @JagbirSingh To avoid errors if you have only one file or email address, force these to be an array like `$files = @('805775-1.zip')`. (same for the $email variable)